# Jquery prevent click event propagating to inner button

Tags: jquery, html, events, click

I have a div which is a panel.  On this panel I overlay some images which a want to capture the click events separately.  I want to trap the click event when the div is selected but not when any of the buttons are clicked.

My HTML:

```
<div class="html5PlayerPanel">     
    <img src=".delete.png" class="delete">        
</div>
```

I've tried:

```
$('.html5PlayerPanel').on('click', ".delete", function (event) {       
        event.stopPropagation();

        return false;
});
```

and also using the Not selector:

```
$(":not(.delete) .html5PlayerPanel").click(function () {

});
```

However each time when I click the image both the images click event and the background div click events are triggered.

Answer (score 1):

In your original parent click function write,

```
$('.html5PlayerPanel').click(function(event){
    if(!$(event.target).hasClass('delete')){

    }
});
```

If the current clicked target is `'.delete'` do nothing.

Comment: This is a valid approach and does work.  I was however hoping to achieve the same thing using the selector as I feel it's cleaner.

Comment: The selector won't work as you don't have other elements inside. Else I would have suggested `$('.html5PlayerPanel *:not(.delete)').click(`

Comment: @keitn Given your comments and the answer you posted, this is the solution you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was actually related to the timing of the image being added to the markup.  I was setting up the click event before the code to add the image to the panel was hit.  The click event was being hit however the event propagation still seemed to fire.

Comment: Using `$('.html5PlayerPanel').on('click', ".delete",` **requires** that the event bubble up to `.html5PlayerPanel` That's how the `$.on()` bit works.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use a click listener and inside grab the type of the element that you clicked.

```
$('.html5PlayerPanel').on('click',function(event){
    console.log(event.target.nodeName);
    switch(event.target.nodeName){
        case 'DIV':
            console.log('you clicked on the div');
            break;
        case 'IMG':
            console.log('you clicked on the img');
            break;
        default:

    }
})
```

take a look : http://jsfiddle.net/tornado1979/ho7odv3e/
good luck